# Attributes with templateUrl on Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a templateUrl with dynamic content inside a directive, something like:

```
//index.html
...
<directive variable="Hi" />
...
```

---

```
//template.html
<div>{{ variable }}</div>
```

---

With a directive:

```
app.directive("directive",[
    function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "template.html"
       }
    }
]);
```

In this example, what I would like to do is to replace `{{ variable }}` with `"Hi"`, but I don't know how to. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or if you don't want an isolated scope, you can do this:

```
return {        
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, elem ,attr) {
        scope.variable = attr.variable;
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "template.html"
}
```

Comment: Definitely this is the solution that worked best for me (I'm still curious why the other one didn't). Some things in angular can be confusing and I see that I still have to get the drift.

Comment: glad it worked, but make sure you understand the difference with both solutions.  Scopes in directives: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
return {        
    restrict: "E",
    scope:{
        variable: '@',    //Note the '@'
    }
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "template.html"
}
```

- use the '@' character to indicate that you want to pass a ***value***.
- use the '=' character to indicate that you're passing a ***variable by reference***.
- use the '&' character to indicate that you're passing a ***function***.

Comment: That's really useful, I will use this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
return {        
    restrict: "E",
    scope:{
        variable: '=',
    }
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: "template.html"
}
```

Comment: This solution works but gave me some problems with more complex attributes with special characters (accents) and multiple words (gave me an error like "unexpected token acreditativa" with an attribute "Documentacion acreditativa"). I don't know why, @cuttlas solution doesn't seem to produce those errors.

Comment: Try this wrapping the variable in single quotes then double quotes <directive variable="'Hi'" />

Comment: @DaniBarcaCasafont Can you tell me what attribute and attribute value gave you that error?

Comment: The attribute was something like: description="Documentación acreditativa". The first error was caused by the "ó" character. When I removed it, I got the "tokens" error.